# How do I define a function on an object with parameters?

Tags: javascript

I want a function to accept parameters.  This works fine without parameters:

```
myObject: {
    var1: 25,
    fun1: function()
    {
        return 1
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't.

```
myObject: {
    var1: 25,
    fun1: function(par)
    {
        return par
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work. `myObject.fun1("Test")` should return `"Test"`.

Comment: so when you call myObject.fun1('foo'); it does not return "foo?" i use js objects almost exclusively and that is correct... short of the missing semi colon after the last curly brace and the extra comma after your function but that shouldn't cause things to break.

Comment: You should really remove the trailing comma. IE doesn't like it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to assign this object to "myObject"? If so, I think you want `myObject = {...` not `myObject: {...` (equals sign instead of colon). With that change, both your snippets work for me in the JavaScript console.